# how can i give multiple actions to button on iPhone

Tags: uibutton

I have two buttons,if the first button is clicked two textfields will come and the second button dimension will change to next to the textfields.Now if i click the second button one textfield will appear.I did all those things.Now my question is if we click the second button,textfield will appear with what ever the dimensions we have given,but if we click the second button after clicking the first button also dimensions should change.Can any one help to do this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple selectors on a single button for different control states

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vaguely phrased. If I understood correctly, when the second button is pressed, you want two different actions done depending on whether the first button has previously been pressed or not. If that's the case, the solution is to define a boolean flag, which will be set to YES when the first button is pressed, and will be set to NO (if needed) after the second button's action is completed.

In your header file:

```
@interface yourViewController: UIViewController {
    BOOL firstButtonFlag;
}
```

And in yourViewController.m file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     firstButtonFlag = NO; // technically redundant line, just to show the concept
}

-(IBAction)firstButtonPressed {
     firstButtonFlag = YES;
     // whatever action you want done
}

-(IBAction)secondButtonPressed {
     if (firstButtonFlag) {
          // whatever action if first button had been pressed before
          firstButtonFlag = NO;  // resetting the flag for next round
     }
     else {
          // whatever action if first button had NOT been pressed before
     }
}
```